# Pushnotification was missing at Capabilities in xcode

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, sandbox, xcode7.2

Am using Sandbox development certificate after installing certificate to my xcode i couldn't find the push notification pane in target capabilities, can any one tell me the solution

Comment: Could you add some additional description? It's currently not really clear what you're asking. You don't install push certificates in Xcode, and whether you've added a cert or not won't change the visibility of the Push Notification capability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: I want to create a sandbox development certificate for push notification purpose, and I have created certificate. In my developer site its showing like push notification enabled, when I come to xcode- we have the tab capability in target know in there is not getting showing up

Comment: I'm not on my Mac right now to look at Xcode, but perhaps you could attach a screenshot or two of what you're seeing? Do you have a project where it is working to compare with?

Comment: I couldn't able to attach image, Xcode->Target->Capabilities in that location pushnotification was not showing

Comment: Read a push tutorial so you understand the role that the app id, push capabilities, profiles, and certificates all play in that functionality. https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial